# How to take parameter from sharepoint and pass to SSRS report

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010

What I have is a page in sharepoint that has a URL that points to the page the contains a parameter at the end, as in "ttp://theur|?Project=projname and what I need is to somehow pass the value of the Project parameter that is in that URL and pass it to the SSRS report so that I can use it on there.  I am displaying the SSRS report on the sharepoint page as an SSRS report viewer web part.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the report viewer page, you can pass the parameter by appending rp:=value into the query string where  is the name of the report parameter.  For a web part embedded in a SharePoint you may be able to use a querystring filter web part and send the value to the report web part.

Comment: Where would I place the rp:=value at?  Inside of the report in SSRS itself?

Comment: It would be in the url of the report viewer.  At the very end of the url append your rp:=value parameter.